# Oracle: TNS-12532: TNS:invalid argument

Tags: windows, oracle, connection

Trying to establish a connection between my windows box (2003 server) and the oracle (11g) database.

I'm able to successfully ping the oracle host from the windows box. However tnsping command fails with the error tns-12532 error.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Can connect to it okay from another pc?

Comment: Want to post the TNS connect descriptor you're using?

Answer (score 1):

From [the Oracle Error Messages documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/net12500.htm#sthref3514):

> **ORA-12532: TNS:invalid argument**
>
> **Cause:** An internal function received an invalid parameter.
>
> **Action:** Not normally visible to the user. For further details, turn on tracing and reexecute the operation. If error persists, contact Oracle Customer Support.

Have you followed that path yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the obvious question, but have you confirmed that you can connect to the db from another pc?